# Ajax call ORA-01403: NO DATA FOUND

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1

I've found out a lot of similar question about this error on stackoverflow, but no one the same of my problem. 
I've build a simple page with two Regions. The first region has two select lists and the second Region has a chart who takes data from the select lists. When I open the page, Apex loads every componts Regions, items... 
I know in my case that initially my chart hasn't data from the select lists and the select below return 0 rows and I get the error message:"AJAX call ORA-01403: NO DATA FOUND". 
When the page has been loaded, I can use the select lists and show value from the chart.

```
select MSO_DEVICE,  nvl((case when MSO_OEE < 100  then 100 else 100 end),0) max_value,  nvl((case when MSO_OEE is null
                                                                                              then 0
                                                                                          when MSO_OEE = 0            
                                                                                               then 0                
                                                                                          else MSO_OEE 
                                                                                           end),0) value           
FROM MES_OEE
where MSO_DEVICE = :P2_DEVICE 
and MSO_DATE = :P2_DATE 
order by 2 desc;
```

I've tryed to set a server condition on Chart region when P2_DEVICE and P2_DATE are null, but in this case the region not appear. In this case I would like to show the region chart with no value or value "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for my problem. I hope it'll be helpful for many people.

```
select  
    mso_device  
  , 100 max_value  
  , coalesce(mso_oee, 0) value                                                                                 
from  
    (select  
        mso_device  
      , mso_oee  
    from  
        mes_oee  
    where  
        mso_device = :p5_device  
    and mso_date = to_date(:p5_date, :APP_NLS_DATE_FORMAT)  
    union all  
    select  
        null  
      , null  
    from  
        dual  
    where  
        :p5_device is null  
    or  :p5_date is null)  
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```